# STL vector and NSArray speed

Tags: objective-c, stl, vector, nsarray

Is `STL` vector faster than `NSArray`? `NSArray` looks somewhat more checked and slower. If `vector` is faster, is there any way I can get `STL` in `objective-c`?

Comment: Dani: This really depends on the implementation. You should simply try it. Write a small program in C++ and Objective-C using these data-structures and see which is faster.

Comment: I guess that you should profile your code.

Comment: You might be interested in reading [this](http://ridiculousfish.com/blog/archives/2005/12/23/array/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use STL, you should go for Objective-C++, which you can think of as the same as Objective-C, but based on C++.

This will allow you to use straight C++ with .cpp files and combination code (objective-C mixed with C++) with .mm files.

(You don't really need doiong anything special to use it, it's fully supported by Xcode once you adopt the .mm convention for mixed languages files)